# Accessing each pixel of a Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

Today I stumbled across this (for me) weird thing, namely when I run this code

```
int i,j;
uint8_t* p = y.data;
for( i = 0; i < y.rows; ++i)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < y.cols; ++j)
    {
       std::cout << y.at<double>(i,j) << std::endl;
       std::cout << saturate_cast<double>(p[i*y.cols + j]) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the output I get looks like this:

```
0.00683212
251
0.00683212
123
0.00683212
63
0.00683212
254
0.00683212
251
0.00683212
123
...
```

can someone explain to me why is it so?

Shouldn't it be same?

Comment: `cout << int( y.at<uchar>(i,j) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what it looks like the memory pointed at by `p` is:

```
// |251 |123 |63  |254 |...   uint8_t
// +----+----+----+----+----+
// | FB | 7B | 3F | FE |... | hex
// +----+----+----+----+----+
// |0.00683212          ...   double
```

when you do `y.at<double>(i,j)` what's essentially going on is:

```
p[i*y.cols + j]
```

you are accessing the array as a `uint8_t` and therefore get a `uint8_t` which converted to `double` keeps the same value. When you access it through `.at<double>()`, its accessing it as a `double*`